# Can't set password for root /localhost Mysql in Macos X Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard, mysql-workbench

Trying to configurate localhost database password for Mysql in Macos x Snow Leopard:

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'password'
```

And I got this error:

> -bash: mysqladmin: command not found

Comment: Perhaps the command `mysqladmin` was not found.  Is the binary in your path?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think the binary is not set. How can I do it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the OS X mysql installer from mysql.com, you'll need to add the mysql bin to your path. You can do this in your `.bash_profile`, for instance.

```
PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

Then you should be able to type `which mysqladmin` and see `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin` as the result.

Comment: I have done this : sudo nano .bash_profile. Then I added the path and save, but when I type /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin nothing is shown. Many thanks.